# How to skip the method if the event is generated from specified button?

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events

This is in continuation of

[How to attach an event to onSubmit event of form with chaining earlier attached methods as well?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613744/how-to-attach-an-event-to-onsubmit-event-of-form-with-chaining-earlier-attached-m)

Now, I am having `disablePage` method which will be executed every time there is any submit event occurs, but I don't want this method to execute if the event is generated from export button.

```
<input type="submit" name="_export" id="btnExportID"  />
```

How can I handle this?

Comment: Is there more than one way to submit your page other than the _export button? I'm trying to understand your problem...

Comment: Also - I think the success of JQuery really hampers the ability to search any vanilla JavaScript solutions :/ (I realise you want a non JQuery solution!).

Comment: @Rew: yes there are lots of submit button and one of them is Export.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

quick-n-dirty: declare a variable `var exportClicked` set it on click of `_export` button. in `disablePage` check if the source is `_export` and pass it.

```
function disablePage(){
    if(exportClicked){
        exportClicked=false;
        return;
    }

   //block page...
}
```

.

```
<input type="submit" name="_export" id="btnExportID" 
       onclick="exportClick();" />

function exportClick(){
    exportClicked = true;
    document.getElementsByTagName('Form')[0].submit();
}
```

Comment: though it is dirty, but i guess this is the only solution.

Comment: let's see if someone can come with something cleaner.